# Dodge w150 318 727 torqueflite; need help with wiring

Tags: dodge, wiring, ground, firewall

We just got done putting motor back in but a ground wire from the head to the fire wall keeps getting hot and smoking (steel braided wire) we've been all over this thing and cant find out our problem

Comment: You missed connecting another ground somewhere. A whole bunch of current is trying to find it's way through the braided wire. If you have a clamp on amp meter, check the direction of the current. If it's going block to body then you missed an engine ground. If it's going body to block then you missed a body ground.

Comment: @vini_i  That sounds like a legitimate answer to the question.  Short but sweet.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a bad ground.  I would install new ground wires.  Get some heavy cable (like 2-6 gauge multi strand) and solder some lugs onto it.  Wire the battery to body, then that same point on the body to the block.  Make sure all spots are nice and clean.  Be sure to give yourself some slack